# How Can I Paste Text From Another Application Into Visual Studio with Emacs Emulation Extension?

Tags: visual-studio, emacs

After copying text from another program, when I switch to Visual Studio with the Emacs Emulation extension and try to paste the text, none of the following methods work:

- Ctrl-Y (Emacs emulation extension keybinding for 'yank' [paste])
- Clicking paste on the toolbar
- Edit > Paste
- Right click > paste

**How can I paste text from an outside application into a copy of Visual Studio that is running the [Emacs Emulation extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/09dc58c4-6f47-413a-9176-742be7463f92)**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl-Shift-Ins` (`Edit.CycleClipboardRing`) will paste the contents of the Windows clipboard into Visual Studio.

As far as the other, more standard methods not working, this is a known bug in the Emacs Emulation extension. From [the extension's Visual Studio Gallery page](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/09dc58c4-6f47-413a-9176-742be7463f92):

> Cut/copy/paste from other applications into Visual Studio does not work with the Emacs extension installed.  We're working on a fix for this issue and will post an updated version of the extension when a fix is available.

Answer (score 6):

As above - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ins</kbd> (`Edit.CycleClipboardRing`) does work for this (at least it does for me having got the emacs add-in to load in VS2012,) so you can then go into Tools->Options, select Environment->Keyboard, and remove the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> shortcut, then assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> to `Edit.CycleClipboardRing`.

Repeating <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> does cycle the clipboard ring, which is a side-effect I can live with... I guess if you reassign <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> to be the same command then generally this will do what you expect.